# Как сделать input type text с проверкой времени (мм:cc) по регулярному выражению

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, input

Всем добрый вечер. Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает как работать адекватно с input) Я написал вот такой пример таймлайна. Я хочу сделать так чтобы я мог задавать значение в ручную в timeBlock через input type text с регулярным выражением который бы мне позволял передвигать ползунок опираясь на введенное значение, а если происходит Drag and Drop то в Input отображется текущее время при передвижении. В input вводится только числа в таком паттерне 00:00 которые не могут превышать максимальное время таймлайна и при изменении времени ":" - данный знак я стереть не могу. Я знаю что можно это сделать через регулярные выражения, но перерыв интернет не смог найти адекватных примеров.

```js
const timeLine = document.getElementById('timeline').getBoundingClientRect();
const timeBLock = document.getElementById('timeBLock');
const timeInput = document.getElementById('timeInput');
const marker = document.getElementById('marker');

const oneHourInSeconds = 3600;

const xAxisTimeRange = [0, 100];

marker.onmousedown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
    document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    const pos = calcInRange(0, e.pageX - timeLine.left, timeLine.width);
    marker.style.left = '' + pos + 'px';
    timeBLock.style.left = '' + pos - 17 + 'px';
    const ratio = getRatio(pos, timeLine.width);
    const time = getTime(ratio, xAxisTimeRange[1]);
    timeInput.value = parseTime(time);
  }
  document.onmouseup = (e) => {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
  }
};

const getRatio = (value, rangeWidth) => {
    return value / rangeWidth;
}

const getTime = (ratio, rangeTime) => {
    return ratio * rangeTime;
}

const calcInRange = (minRange, value, maxRange) => {
      return Math.max(Math.min(value, maxRange), minRange);
   }
   
const parseTime = (second) => {
      let formatted = new Date(second * 1000).toUTCString().split(/ /)[4];
      if (second < oneHourInSeconds) {
         formatted = formatted.slice(3);
      } else if (second >= oneHourInSeconds) {
         formatted = formatted.slice(1);
      }
      return formatted;
   }
```

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.marker {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.timeBLock {
  color: white;
  left: -17px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline" class="timeline">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div id="timeBLock" class="timeBLock">
    <input id="timeInput" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="marker" class="marker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прочитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]. Надо привести однозначные примеры текстов и что в них найти. В данном случае валидные и невалидные инпуты

Answer (score -1):

Вот так вот:

```
^[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5b487

> **12:43**
>
> 32:211
>
> **59:59**
>
> 59:60
>
> 60:59
>
> **05:00**
>
> **05:01**
>
> 1:54

Comment: Та за шо минус?